# Github Pro: How to give read only access to a private repository?

Tags: github

We have a Github pro account and have a Github repository for which we want to give read-only access to a few people. They should be able to get the code with this access but shouldn't be to modify this repository in any way.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to allow them to clone the repository but still modify it on their own system, you can do this by either assigning them as collaborators on the repository with the read privilege under Settings → Manage Access.

If your goal is to prevent them from modifying the repository even on their own systems once it's cloned, then that isn't possible.

Comment: Is this feature available in Github pro? Seems like this is Github enterprise feature. Any workaround for Github pro?

Comment: I have GitHub Pro, and it's available on my account.  It's a per-repo setting, so it's in the repository settings, not the account settings.

Comment: Could you please share some steps / screenshot of modifying this per-repo setting. Unable to find it. Thanks.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of steps I follow to give someone access to repository - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mBVkz8GeEC1B6M07amjJLq0ckrgr0LYqK-iGOLHI8Tw/edit?usp=sharing  I am not able to see how do I give read-only access to a collaborator?

Comment: I gave up on this. It looks like there's not an easy read-only access token for private repos, which sucks because I think that would be nice to have on servers running a git clone script.

Comment: If you want a way to do read-only clones, use SSH and a deploy key.  Those are specifically intended to provide limited access to a single repo.